# Google Maps Heatmap Layer Only Displays in Some Browsers

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I have a rather baffling problem with a Google Maps heatmap layer: it displays fine in Firefox, but refuses to do so in Chrome or Safari.

A demonstration:
http://dev.nomad.cm/projects/maps/map.html

Neither Chrome nor Safari throws any errors in the console, so I don't really have anything concrete to go on. I suspect possible memory limits: the JSON of lat/long points I'm loading is ~150,000 items. Still, if this was the issue, I'd think an error would be thrown up.

Very simple code (including skeleton HTML):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Heatmap Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    html { height: 100% }
    body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
    #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=visualization"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajaxPrefilter( "json script", function( options ) {
      options.crossDomain = true;
    });

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        var layoffLocs = new Array();
        $.getJSON('map_points.json', function(data) { 
            $.each(data.points, function(i, value) {
                layoffLocs.push(new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat, value.lon));
            });
        });
        var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(layoffLocs);
        var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: pointArray
        });
        heatmap.setMap(map);
        // google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 800px; height: 600px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sample excerpt from JSON:

```
{
"points":[
    {"lat":40.025312,"lon":-83.091194},
    {"lat":40.754308,"lon":-84.081579},
    {"lat":40.141624,"lon":-82.978615},
    {"lat":39.416894,"lon":-81.429982},
    {"lat":39.450391,"lon":-84.476614}
]
}
```

Any insights greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you're  trying to render the heatmap before the data has loaded.
Shouldn't you be doing it in the callback function of the json load, something like:

```
 $.getJSON('map_points.json', function(data) { 
        $.each(data.points, function(i, value) {
            layoffLocs.push(new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat, value.lon));
        });

        var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(layoffLocs);
        var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: pointArray
        });
        heatmap.setMap(map);
});
```

Comment: I feel incredibly stupid now. I got so caught up in the fact that (for whatever reason) it was working in Firefox but not Chrome that I totally missed this obvious error. Thank you!